# How does the vote-cancellation mechanism work?

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-question, voting-anomaly-detection

Today, I was a victim of an "upvote cluster" cast by a community member as a result of [his satisfaction with an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241169/2241243#2241243).

Naturally, this upvote cluster is expected to be caught by the voting anomaly detection in the system. As expected, my rep got down a little bit (by ~300) which made me think of a possible issue in the system and brought me here to ask this question. What exactly happens after the anomaly detector detects a suspicious vote cluster?

It should do one of:

1. Cancels the votes in that specific cluster.
2. Cancels *all votes* ever cast by that person towards you.
3. Cancels *all votes* ever cast by that person.

And one of the following:

1. Totally recalcs the rep of the target member.
2. Adjusts the rep of the target member by removing the rep caused by that specific vote cluster.

If the answer to the first question is 1 && the answer to the second is 2, then the system is likely to have a bug, since I believe the amount of rep I've got from that person in that cluster was about 100, at most. Otherwise, if there was a recalc (which takes off the rep from deleted answers), or if all votes ever cast are canceled, the system is probably working normally.

Comment: The recalc will take into account deleted posts so you will lose more than the ~100 points from this cluster.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yeah, I thought so, but I expected losing more than 300 points if a complete recalc is done. I thought I have deleted more posts. That's why I was suspicious of a bug. I may have been wrong though. Guess it's compensated by being over cap.

Comment: If you hit the rep cap on any day that now has deleted posts you'll earn the points that you missed the first time round.

Comment: I know that. I was talking about the past days where I have earned rep from posts that I subsequently deleted.  The point of my question is, however, is a *complete recalc* is done, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a complete recalc is done. There is no such thing as a partial recalc.